# How to access certain values inside a string in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, facebook-graph-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

I need to extract only a particular element value inside the string. 
Below is the code which I used to get the AdsInsight data using Facebook AdsInsight API.

```
class LibFacebook:
    def __init__(self, app_id, app_secret, access_token, ad_account_id):
        FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)
        self.account = AdAccount(ad_account_id)
      #get ads insight
        insights = self.account.get_insights(fields=[
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
        AdsInsights.Field.actions,
], params={
        'level': AdsInsights.Level.campaign,
        })
        print(insights)
```

**Output**

```
<AdsInsights> {
    "campaign_id": "23843294609751234",
    "actions": [
        {
            "action_type": "post_reaction",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "landing_page_view",
            "value": "78"
        },
        {
            "action_type": "link_click",
            "value": "163"
        }
       ]
```

**Question** : Along with campaign_id value(23843294609751234) , I need the value of only *landing_page_view* i.e 78 (and not other action items)and put it in a df. How do I access them ?

Further Information: AdsInsights.Field.actions is of type string.

```
type(AdsInsights.Field.actions)

str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this will work,
lets take your data is a list of `AdsInsights` objects

```
obj = [{
    "campaign_id": "23843294609751234",
    "actions" : [

            {
                "action_type": "post_reaction",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "action_type": "landing_page_view",
                "value": "78"
            },
            {
                "action_type": "link_click",
                "value": "163"
            }
           ]
},

 {
    "campaign_id": "112233",
    "actions" : [

            {
                "action_type": "post_reaction",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "action_type": "landing_page_view",
                "value": "100"
            },
            {
                "action_type": "link_click",
                "value": "163"
            }
           ]
}]
```

you can get result like this

```
result_arr = []
for i in obj:
    datadict = {}  
    datadict["campaign_id"] = i.get("campaign_id")
    for action in i.get("actions"):
        if action.get("action_type") == "landing_page_view":
            datadict["value"]= action.get("value")
            result_arr.append(datadict)
```

`result_arr` would be

```
[{'campaign_id': '23843294609751234', 'value': '78'},
 {'campaign_id': '112233', 'value': '100'}]
```

next convert list of dictionaries to a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame(result_arr)
```